# How to iterate through list of objects and get Id of particular object using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am building a simple CRUD app using `SpringBoot`, `Hibernate` and `JPA`. I am very new to using Hibernate and just figuring it out.

Furthermore, I have a many-to-many association and as a result to that association a third table is created.

The third table is consisted of two primary keys `user_id` and `sport_id`.
I am having a hard time populating that table.

I am sending JSON object via Postman like `RequestBody`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "sport_id": 1,
        "user_id": 2
    }
]
```

**SportUsersController.java**

```
@PostMapping("/sportsUsers")
    public void saveSportsUsers(@RequestBody List<SportUser> sportUserList){
        this.sportUserService.saveSportUser(sportUserList);
    }
```

**SportUsersDaoImpl.java**

```
 @Override
    public void saveSportUser(List<SportUser> sportUserList) {

        for (SportUser sportUser : sportUserList){

            User user = (User) entityManager.createQuery("from Users u where u.id = :sportUser.getUser()")
                    .setParameter("User", sportUser.getUser())
                    .getSingleResult();

            Sport sport = (Sport) entityManager.createQuery("from Sport s where s.id = :sportUser.getSport()")
                    .setParameter("Sport", sportUser.getSport())
                    .getSingleResult();

            sportUser = (SportUser) entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("saveSportUser")
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .setParameter(1, sport)
                    .setParameter(2, user);

            entityManager.merge(sportUser);
        }
    }
```

I was trying to do something like this but of course query `from Users u where u.id = :sportUser.getUser()` is not working because of `u.id = :sportUser.getUser()` is not correct syntax.

**SportUser.java**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "Sport_Users")
@ApiModel(description = "All details about sport an users")
public class SportUser {

    /**
     * unique SportUsers number, auto generated
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    /**
     * object sport
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Sport.class)//load it on-demand
    @JoinColumn(name = "sport_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Sport sport;

    /**
     * object user, user who plays sport
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = User.class)//load it on-demand
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

}
```

I am not sure how to write query to get id from list for User and for Sport.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to mess with this table manually? If you use JPA correctly, you should usually not touch this table yourself but it will be automatically handled by Hibernate.

Comment: What do you mean? How would it be managed automatically?

Comment: I added my entity in the question take a look

Comment: If you really just want a n:m relationship between users and sports without additional fields, you do not need this additional entity to connect them. In the User entity, create a field List<Sport> sports with ManyToMany and in the Sport entity create a field List<User> users with ManyToMany. This will automatically create a mapping table and you don't have to deal with anything yourself. Note that one side (either User or Sport) has to be the owning side of the relationship and the other one has to be the non-owning side (declare by the "mappedBy" attribute of the ManyToMany annotation)

Comment: Hi I have to change my code to your example, but now I am getting an infinite loop.

Comment: @Philipp I found a solution to my question and posted it as an answer you can check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the working solution I was looking for thanks to @kameshsr and @Philipp directions.

So I changed my entities to look like this:

**User.java**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Sport_Users",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sport_id"))
    private Set<Sport> sports = new HashSet<>();
```

**Sport.java**

```
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sports")
    Set<User> user = new HashSet<>();
```

I want to be able to save a list of users at one go and be able to connect user to sport. So I used java streams to do that.

This is how my code looks like:

```
    @Override
    public void saveUser(List<User> newUsers) {
        for(User user : newUsers) {
            user.getSports()
                    .addAll(user.getSports().stream()
                    .map(s -> { Sport sport = sportDao.getSportById(s.getId());
                    sport.getUser().add(user);
                    return sport;
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            entityManager.merge(user);
        }
    }
```

Hope that it helps someone with same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use many to many like this.
Your sports model might look like this.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
        @JoinTable(name = "Sport_Users",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "sport_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
        private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

And in your user class do something like this.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Sport> sports = new HashSet<>();
```

No need to join the table manually. [See](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) for better explanation.

Comment: I have tried your example, but I am getting an infinite loop when I am using it

Comment: I have made one spelling mistake. I corrected it. In child class mappedBy use same variable name defined in parent class like in parent class, I defined set<User> users variable then in child class when you are using mappedBy use this same variable users not your table name. This may solve your problem.

Comment: Hi I found a way to get rid of an infinite loop. I added `@JsonIgnore` to child object. Here is a very good link of how to do it https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion. But my question was how to populate third table or table `Sport_User`?

Comment: no need to manually populate the third table. If you will write your models like in my answer then maybe your third table will be automatically populated because it works for me when I am doing a project last week.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how you'd it be populated automatically? Because if I look at my database table Users I don't have any column that contains sport

Comment: [see this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) tutorial here no need to create a connection table too everything created automatically by JPA.

Comment: Well I think maybe to add something like `user.getSport();` part to my code is needed.. definitely not sure

Comment: HI I found a solution to my question and posted it as answer. You can check it :)